# Ограничить количество замен в методе Replace C#

Tags: c#, python-3.x

С#: Программа должна заменять подстроку 1 раз.

```
string s = new string('1', 45) + new string('2', 45);
while (s.Contains("111"))
{
    s = s.Replace("111", "2");
    s = s.Replace("222", "1");
}
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

> 21

Python:

```
s = '1' * 45 + '2' * 45 
while '111' in s:
    s = s.replace('111', '2', 1)
    s = s.replace('222', '1', 1)
print(s)
```

> 12

Comment: Программы разные. Разницу рекомендую найти самостоятельно.

Comment: Да, видно же, что в питоне замены ограничили одной за раз. Если ограничение убрать, то код выдаст тоже самое, что и C#.

Comment: @pechenb Третий параметр у вызовов `s.replace` уберите и результат будет одинаковый

Comment: @pechenb У `Regex.Replace` есть такой параметр, если очень нужно, можно его использовать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как я уже написал вам в комментарии, для `C#` можно использовать `Regex.Replace` для получения такого же результата, как в питоне:

```cs
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Regex rgx1 = new Regex("111");
Regex rgx2 = new Regex("222");
string s = new string('1', 45) + new string('2', 45);
while (s.Contains("111"))
{
    s = rgx1.Replace(s, "2", 1);
    s = rgx2.Replace(s, "1", 1);
}
Console.WriteLine(s);
```